# Как убирать символы в тексте?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Кароче, у меня есть панель с паролем и я хочу в случае чего убирать вбитые цифры, но не знаю как это реализовать, пробовал через Remove, не выходило

```
public void ButtonClick(int number)
    {

        if (_isResetting) { return; }

        _inputCode.text += number;

        if (_inputCode.text == _cardCode.text)
        {
            _inputCode.text = "Correct";
            StartCoroutine(ResetCode());
        }
        else if (_inputCode.text.Length >= _codeLength)
        {
            _inputCode.text = "Failed";
            StartCoroutine(ResetCode());
        }
    }
```

Вот часть кода для ввода через кнопки пароля
`_inputCode` вводимый код
`_cardCode` пароль

Comment: `_inputCode.text = ""`?

Comment: Не понятно что не так с кодом. Вопрос задан не точно и в нем не хватает деталей проблемы и описания текущей реализации. Можете описать лучше?

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема-то? `объект.GetComponent<Text>().text = ""`

Comment: Нашёл решение
_inputCode.text = string.Empty;